# Reading and creating Username and passsword from CSV File in ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
line=0
cat userDetails.csv |while IFS="," read -r last first grps
do
line=$((line+1))
if [ $line == 1 ]; then
continue
fi
first=echo "$first"|tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' 
last=echo "$last"|tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'
grps=echo "$grps" 
for groupName in echo $grps
do
ret=getent group $groupName
if [ -z $ret ]
then
groupadd $groupName
fi
done
passwd=cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9'|head -c10
user1=echo "$last"|tail -c6
user2=echo "$first"|head -c2
grps=echo "$grps"
if [ ! -z $grps]
then
useradd -G $grps $user1$user2 -p $password
else
useradd $user1$user2 -p $password
fi
echo “user id for $first is: $user1$user2, password: $password”
done
```

This is the code that is reading the CSV file and creating the password, when I run it against the csv File that looks a little like

```
Smith, John
Doe, Jane
```

etc.. And the errors coming out are this

```
./adduser3.sh: line 9:  John: command not found
./adduser3.sh: line 10: Smith: command not found
./adduser3.sh: line 11: : command not found
./adduser3.sh: line 14: group: command not found
groupadd: group 'echo' already exists
./adduser3.sh: line 20: /dev/urandom: Permission denied
./adduser3.sh: line 21: Smith: command not found
./adduser3.sh: line 22:  John: command not found
./adduser3.sh: line 23: : command not found
useradd: option requires an argument -- 'p'
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
       useradd -D
       useradd -D [options]

Options:
  -b, --base-dir BASE_DIR       base directory for the home directory of the
                                new account
  -c, --comment COMMENT         GECOS field of the new account
  -d, --home-dir HOME_DIR       home directory of the new account
  -D, --defaults                print or change default useradd configuration
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  expiration date of the new account
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       password inactivity period of the new account
  -g, --gid GROUP               name or ID of the primary group of the new
                                account
  -G, --groups GROUPS           list of supplementary groups of the new
                                account
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -k, --skel SKEL_DIR           use this alternative skeleton directory
  -K, --key KEY=VALUE           override /etc/login.defs defaults
  -l, --no-log-init             do not add the user to the lastlog and
                                faillog databases
  -m, --create-home             create the user's home directory
  -M, --no-create-home          do not create the user's home directory
  -N, --no-user-group           do not create a group with the same name as
                                the user
  -o, --non-unique              allow to create users with duplicate
                                (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       encrypted password of the new account
  -r, --system                  create a system account
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -s, --shell SHELL             login shell of the new account
  -u, --uid UID                 user ID of the new account
  -U, --user-group              create a group with the same name as the user
  -Z, --selinux-user SEUSER     use a specific SEUSER for the SELinux user mapping
      --extrausers              Use the extra users database
```

I cannot figure as to why the dev/urandom permission is messing up with the cat and why it is spitting out the errors it is giving me

Comment: did you check your code at https://shellcheck.net ? It will probably flag a lot of syntax errors. Be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` as the first line (or whatever shell you want to execute your code). Correct the errors flagged and if you still have trouble, update your Q else if problem solved, please delete it. Good luck.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is `first=echo "$first"` not doing what you think.

To define a variable, you need `var=val`, with no spaces in `val` (or you need to quote it). There is also `var=val command` syntax, where `var` is defined *in a sub-environment* created to run `command` (i.e. temporarily, just for `command` sake). This is what your command does: first it expands `$first` to `John`, then you have the command `first=echo John`, which defines a variable `first` with value `echo` for the duration of the command `John`. And as the error informs you, there is no command `John`.

The correct syntax would be `first=$(echo $first)`, which runs the command `echo $first` and assigns its value to `first`. Or `first="$first"`, which just assigns the value of `first` to `first`. Which makes it very obvious that you are doing something completely unnecessary in the `first` place.

The rest of the code is peppered with the same kind of error, using `echo` unnecessarily, wrongly, or both, or failing to quote properly. You should also make sure to indent your code correctly in the future, both for the benefit of the potential answerers, and also for your own sanity when debugging.